# Make individuals distinct

Tags: logic, computer-science, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to construct an *ALCQ* knowledge base (KB) for some sentences. Here is what I have:

Abox (Yiannis is a person and he drinks only one kind of a coffee, frappe):

- Person(YIANNIS)
- $\forall$ drinksCoffee.frappe(YIANNIS)

Tbox (A Greek person is a person who drinks only one kind of a coffee, frappe):

- Greek $\equiv$ Person $\sqcap$ $\forall$drinksCoffee.frappe

Now I want to augment my KB with the following sentence:

> Yiannis has three distinct pets: Tsipras, Varoufakis and Podemos.

I would add to my Abox these:

- hasPet(YIANNIS, TSIPRAS) // maybe I need $\exists$ symbol in its
  start?
- hasPet(YIANNIS, VAROUFAKIS)
- hasPet(YIANNIS, PODEMOS)

but how to make these pets **distinct**?

Comment: Can you use identity? And thus add e.g. "TSIPRAS $\ne$ VAROUFAKIS"?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but I am new in this, so I do not know if it is that simple @BrianO, is it?

Comment: I'm just guessing. You, however, know something about ALCQ KBs... The question must have an easy answer.

Comment: Hmm OK @BrianO, are you going to answer, or should I delete the question?

Comment: I have no answer beyond that. You can't determine whether identity is allowed in the KB system you're using???

Comment: I am saying to convert your comment to an answer @BrianO. Well, from my understanding it is not, *but* the assignment says strictly to do so with ALCQ. I cannot check, since it's all in paper (!). So I think my understanding is wrong and what you are saying is correct.

Comment: I'm almost embarrassed to do so: it seems I have questions but no answers! And I don't know the notations involved (ABox, TBox, things that look like first order logic, from a distance, but aren't, etc.) When I search ALCQ, I don't find much, and what little I do find is behind paywalls. You only have hardcopy (paper), not a link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35943/discussion-between-gsamaras-and-briano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALCQ is an extension of the Description Language ALC described in the slides at http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~pms509/lectures/dl-intro.pdf. Slide 41 states the *Unique Names Assumption*:

> *Unique Names Assumption* (UNA): We will assume that if
>   $a$ and $b$ are distinct individuals then $a^{\mathcal{I}} \ne b^{\mathcal{I}}$.

Thus, you don't have to do *anything* to ensure that the three distinctly named pets are interpreted as distinct individuals: the UNA states that in every interpretation they are guaranteed to denote distinct individuals. You get it "for free".