# How to apply negation to a term?

Tags: logic, computer-science, artificial-intelligence

EDIT:

Maybe page 18 of this [paper](http://lat.inf.tu-dresden.de/research/papers/2009/Baader09.pdf) can help.

---

This is a follow up from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660766/make-individuals-distinct), where I am using *ALCQ* and I have this:

$\lnot(3 \le \exists \text{hasPet}.\text{Animal})$

How to apply the NOT operator? I thought about:

> $3 \le \exists \text{hasPet}.\lnot\text{Animal}$

which actually works well for making the "*every pet is an animal*" false, but I am worried about the "*he has at least 3 pets*".

---

My thought is driven by this example:

> $\lnot(\forall \text{drinksCoffee}.\text{Frappe}) $

gives:

> $\exists \text{drinksCoffee}.\lnot\text{Frappe}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment*

The expression ∀hasPet.Animal means:

> the set of individuals that have pets that are animal.

It stay for a *concept* i.e. defines a set. See the interpretation:

> $\{ \ a \in D^I \mid ∀b \ [(a,b) \in \text{hasPet}^I \to b \in \text{Animal}^I ] \ \ \}$.

Thus we can "negate" it: ¬(∀hasPet.Animal) getting the complement of the previous set:

> $\{ \ a \in D^I \mid ∃b \ [(a,b) \in \text{hasPet}^I \land b \notin \text{Animal}^I ] \ \ \}$

that we symbolize as ∃hasPet.¬Animal.

---

Usually the *number restrictions*: $\ge n$ R (at-least restriction) and $\le n$ R (at-most restriction), are "applied" to *roles*. The expression: $3 \le$hasPet stay for:

> the set of individuals that have at least $3$ pets.

If so, what does it mean the expression ($3 \le$ ∀hasPet.Animal) where the number restriction is applied to a *concept* ?

I think that we have to read it as:

> the set of individuals that have pets that are animal has at least three members.

I.e. the number restriction is on the members of the *concept* "hasPet.Animal" and not on the number of pets.

Comment: Mauro thanks for your answer. I see we agree in $∃hasPet.¬Animal$. As for the $(3≤ ∀hasPet.Animal)$, I would say that it means: the set of individuals that have at least three pets, which are animals. Does this help?

Comment: @gsamaras - if this is the correct interpretation, negating it we get the complement of the said set.

Comment: I think that's the point of negation Mauro, isn't it? However I am not sure on how to do apply negation on it.

Comment: How about $∃hasPet.¬Animal \sqcup  (2 \geq ∀hasPet.Animal)$?

Comment: Page 18 from here http://lat.inf.tu-dresden.de/research/papers/2009/Baader09.pdf may shed some light..